# Position widget doesnot work when child is FractionallySizedBox in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create a custom widget like Badge where two circle shapped container as a stack children...

I dont want to use inbuild badge widget as i want to create with code..for learning purpose

here i am using FractionallySized box becuase i want small cirle's size should b mainCirlc's size*0.20, and when i apply Position right 0 and top 0 its showing error

**Box Contraints forces an infinitive width**

```
class CustomWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomWidget({Key? key,}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Stack(
        clipBehavior: Clip.none,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: [
          //Main Circle
          FractionallySizedBox(

            heightFactor: 1,
            widthFactor: 1,
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.red,
                shape: BoxShape.circle
              ),
            ),
          ),
          //badge circle
          Positioned(
            top: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            child: FractionallySizedBox(
              heightFactor: 0.2,
              widthFactor: 0.2,
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.yellow,
                    shape: BoxShape.circle
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `Stack` with `SizedBox` or use `Expanded`. Stack has infinite height and width. `FractionallySizedBox` is supposed to be a fraction of parent but parent is infinite so it throws error.

An alternative to `FractionallySizedBox` is using `SizedBox` and explicitly adding factor of dimension for the dimension parameter.

eg :

```
 return SizedBox(
          height:MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.3,
          child:Text(
           'Hello, World!',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
        ),
    );
```